# What's the alternative to u32::BITS in a const?

Tags: rust

I have a bit of code that does this:

```
const MY_CRAZY_CONSTANT: u32 = 1 << (u32::BITS - 1);
```

I tried to compile it using Rust nightly (2016-03-29) and it fails with the message:

```
error: no associated item named `BITS` found for type `u32` in the current scope
```

I see that it was deprecated and I see there was an RFC ([Sizeof, alignof, offsetof, typeof #591](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/591)) talking about adding a sizeof keyword etc, but that is closed: postponed.

I guess the deprecation has come to fruition in the nightly channel in that it has been removed and I know I can do the following, but to do that I would need to remove my const, which I would rather not do.

```
mem::size_of::<u32>() * 8
```

So, is it now the case that I must remove my const and re-structure my code or is there some other way to achieve what I had originally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer is to define your own constant:

```
const U32_BITS: usize = 32;
```

for the special case of `usize::BITS` or `isize::BITS`, you will need to use conditional compilation.

```
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
const USIZE_BITS: usize = 32;
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]
const USIZE_BITS: usize = 64;
```