# How do I use the byteorder crate to read a usize?

Tags: rust

I'm writing an encoding library and I'd like to convert a `slice` into a `usize`.

I see a [`read_uint`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.1.0/byteorder/trait.ReadBytesExt.html#method.read_uint) method that looks promising, though I'm unsure how to get the register size as a variable so I can put it in the function.

For example I'd like to get `32` on a 32 bit processor, and `64` on a 64 bit processor.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How to get the size of a user defined struct? (sizeof)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664327/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-user-defined-struct-sizeof) and [What's the alternative to u32::BITS in a const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285396/whats-the-alternative-to-u32bits-in-a-const)

Comment: Note that use usize in a data format is a bad idea. Prefer something like u64 with bound checking. (That also why this function doesn't exist in byteorder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [`mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) to get the size of a `usize`:

```
use byteorder::{ByteOrder, ReadBytesExt};

fn read_usize<B, R>(mut b: R) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error>
where
    B: ByteOrder,
    R: ReadBytesExt,
{
    b.read_uint::<B>(std::mem::size_of::<usize>()).map(|v| v as usize)
}
```

Another is to have different functions or function implementations for different architectures:

```
fn read_usize<B, R>(mut b: R) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error>
where
    B: ByteOrder,
    R: ReadBytesExt,
{
    if cfg!(target_pointer_width = "64") {
        b.read_u64::<B>().map(|v| v as usize)
    } else if cfg!(target_pointer_width = "32") {
        b.read_u32::<B>().map(|v| v as usize)
    } else {
        b.read_u16::<B>().map(|v| v as usize)
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to get the size of a user defined struct? (sizeof)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36664327/155423)
- [How to check in Rust if architecture is 32 or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41896462/155423)

Comment: While this answer is technically correct (like all (?) of your answers) I would not suggest to do something like this and point out, that this is normally not a wanted behavior.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR there is a good reason for not providing a `read_usize` function, because it is not consistent on different cpu-architectures.

---

This is a bad idea. Normally you have some kind of protocol you are trying to deserialize. This format should be independent from the cpu-architecture and therefore you can't read an usize, because it is cpu-dependent.

Let's assume you have a simple protocol where you first have the size of an array and afterwards `n` elements.

```
+------+---------+
| size | ....... |
+------+---------+
```

Let's suppose the protocol says that your size is 4 byte long. Now you want to do the thing Shepmaster suggested and read the usize dependent on your architecture.

On a x86_64 OS you will now read 8 bytes and therefore swallow the first element in your array.
On a Atmega8 your usize would be 2 bytes and therefore only take the first 2 bytes of your size (which might be zero in case there are less than 65k elements and a BigEndian byte-order).

This is the reason why there is no `read_usize` function and it is correct. You need to decide how long your size is, read the exact amount of bytes from your slice and then us `as` to convert that into an `usize`.

Comment: I agree, but the OP specifically stated that they understand that they will get different results on different platforms. This is a design decision that is acceptable to make, so long as you understand the tradeoffs.

Comment: For example, "the protocol" might be a dump of RAM that is never supposed to cross architectures.

Comment: In that case that it is helpful, yes.

Comment: @Shepmaster In this case, you simply don't need ByteOrder. your platform will not change of endianess ;)

Comment: For the record, `byteorder` extends `Read` and `Write` with primitive reading and writing functions (e.g. `read_u32`) and as such, is not completely useless when only working under the system's native endianness.